# Kotlin : How to convert Array<List> to arrayof?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, linechart

So, I try to make a line chart using AAChartModel. I have ArrayList in my code. But in AAchartModel they used an arrayOf instead of ArrayList.

[image]

So My Question is, how do I convert from ArrayList to arrayOf ?

Comment: Either this question is a duplicate of [Java ArrayList to Kotlin Array](//stackoverflow.com/q/31593234) or it is unclear due to misleading usage of class names and types.

Answer (score 2):

`arrayOf()` returns just an `Array`. So you can call `arrayList.toTypedArray()`